# Apply function to every line in csv file

Tags: python

I have a function [from Vasilis G.'s answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790546/calculate-days-between-several-dates-in-python/69790813#69790813):

> ```
> from datetime import datetime
>
> def getTotal(line):
>     dates = list(datetime.strptime(elem, '%Y-%m-%d') for elem in line.split(', '))
>     total = 0
>     for i in range(0, len(dates), 2):
>         delta = dates[i+1] - dates[i]
>         if delta.days > 90:
>             total += 2
>         else:
>             total += 1
>     return total
> ```

I then used:

```
with open('dataset.csv','r') as csvfile:  # use with to auto-close file
   for row in csvfile.readlines():  # pin_id
       getTotal(row)  # board_id and section can use defaults
       time.sleep(random.randint(1,3)) # wait 1-3 seconds
```

And I would like to apply it on every line in my csv file but it's giving me `"ValueError : unconverted data remains : 2022-06-03,2021-05-29,2024-06-03,2022-05-29,2026-06-03,2023-05-29,2028-06-03,2024-05-29,2030-06-03,2025-05-29,2032-06-03` which coincide with the first line of my .csv file.

**FINAL**:

```
from datetime import datetime


def getTotal(line):
    dates = [datetime.strptime(elem.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d') for elem in line.split(',')]
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, len(dates), 2):
        delta = dates[i+1] - dates[i]
        if delta.days > 90:
            total += 2
        else:
            total += 1
    return total

print(getTotal(dates))
with open('dataset.csv','r') as csvfile:  
   for row in csvfile.readlines():  
       getTotal(row)
```

Comment: you are saying to split by a comma then a space. But the values in your output are split only by a comma and no space. There for they count as one element. which you then try to apply your string parse time call to, and its saying well after parsing your string there is still uncoverted data. Did you mean `line.split(',')`?

Comment: If your line sometimes contains whitespace, consider something like `elem.strip()` where you now use `elem`, combined with `line.split(',')`

Comment: Indeed, I fixed it. But Now I have this error `ValueError: time data ' 2023-01-02' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: Use `strip` as Grismar suggested.

Comment: I fixed all the whitespace. There is none anymore. I'm still getting `ValueError: unconverted data remains:`

Comment: For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete but minimal code (to start, `dates` is not defined and `time.sleep` is irrelevant), example input (`dataset.csv`), and expected output. It'd also help to add the full error message with traceback, for completeness.

Comment: Are you aware of the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)? That could make this a whole lot simpler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def getTotal(line):
    dates = [datetime.strptime(elem.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d') for elem in line.split(',')]
    ...
```

Comment: I edited my question to add the final code using yours. It's working with no error but nothing is being printed

Comment: Is your `for loop` supposed to be like this? `for row in csvfile.readlines(): print(getTotal(row))`